Why does my precision suddenly drop to 0.5?
I am working on a binary classification problem that will classify variable stars between Heartbeat stars and ECL stars from their light curve. When I run my code, the recall  increases to 1 as the precision suddenly drops to 0.5. 
But when I analyze the epochs, this doesn't seem to be happening:

Here's the relevant sections of my code:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, PrecisionRecallDisplay
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Convert columns to numeric, coercing errors to NaN
df['HJD-2450000'] = pd.to_numeric(df['HJD-2450000'], errors='coerce')
df['mag'] = pd.to_numeric(df['mag'], errors='coerce')

# Handle any NaN values if they exist
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Create binary labels
df['Type'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x.startswith('HB') else 1)

# Feature scaling
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(df[['HJD-2450000', 'mag']])

# Add polynomial features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
poly_features = poly.fit_transform(scaled_features)

# Update DataFrame with new features
df_poly = pd.DataFrame(poly_features, columns=poly.get_feature_names_out())
df_poly['Type'] = df['Type']

# Separate majority and minority classes
X = df_poly.drop('Type', axis=1)
y = df_poly['Type']

# Handle class imbalance with SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(random_state=29130)
X_resampled, y_resampled = smote.fit_resample(X, y)

# Split into train and test datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=0.2, random_state=29130)

# Define model inputs
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],), dtype=tf.float32, name='features')

# Model architecture with regularization
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
dense_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

def create_model(my_inputs, my_outputs, my_learning_rate):
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=my_inputs, outputs=my_outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=my_learning_rate),
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'), tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='BA')])
    return model

learning_rate = 0.001  # Use Adam optimizer with a lower learning rate
my_model = create_model(inputs, dense_output, learning_rate)

# Train the model with early stopping
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

def train_model(model, features, labels, epochs, batch_size):
    history = model.fit(x=features, y=labels, batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[early_stopping])
    epochs = history.epoch
    hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
    ba = hist["BA"]
    return epochs, ba

epochs, ba = train_model(my_model, X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=64)

# Plotting the accuracy curve
def plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, ba):
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel("Binary Accuracy")
    plt.plot(epochs, ba, label="Binary Accuracy")
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim([ba.min()*0.94, ba.max()*1.05])
    plt.show()

plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, ba)

# Evaluate the model and plot precision-recall curve
def plot_precision_recall_curve(model, features, labels):
    # Predict probabilities
    y_scores = model.predict(features).ravel()

    # Calculate precision and recall at different thresholds
    precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(labels, y_scores)

    # Plot the precision-recall curve
    display = PrecisionRecallDisplay(precision=precision, recall=recall)
    display.plot()
    plt.title("Precision-Recall Curve")
    plt.show()

plot_precision_recall_curve(my_model, X_test, y_test)

# Evaluate the model
evaluation = my_model.evaluate(x=X_test, y=y_test, batch_size=64)
print(f"Model AUC: {evaluation[1]}")


I am using the time value and the magnitude (luminosity) value as my features to observe the light curve as the variable star changes over time
Is there something I'm missing? What I think is happening is that since this is an imbalanced class set (ECL stars make up 90% of the set) the model is just classifying everything as an ECL star. How do I prevent this from happening? Or specifically, is there something wrong with my features in particular? Do I have to take a cross product of time and magnitude to capture their relation to the computer?
I have tried dropping come of the ECL stars' value, but the precession keeps dropping to 0.5

The question is based on misconceptions on how ROC curves are built, there is no programming problem here.

Your precision-recall curve actually showed a relatively great result!
The sudden drop in precision value as recall approaches 1 should not be confused with poor model performance. This link from sklearn explained how to interpret the curve.
The curve shows the performance of my_model after the last epoch of your training as the return value of train_model, so the curve has nothing to do with loss and accuracy values in each epoch in the training history.
The precision-recall curve plots different precision-recall values of your model on a dataset (in this case X_test and y_test) across various threshold values.
Suppose your test dataset consists of 50 positive and 50 negative. For example, if the threshold is -infinity, all y values produced by the model on X_test are greater than the threshold and would therefore be classified as positive, i.e. TP = 50, FP = 50, TN = 0, FN = 0. This corresponds to the (1, 0.5) point in the curve since precision = TP/(TP+FP) = 0.5 and recall = TP/(TP+FN) = 1. Do it with other threshold values and you get the precision-recall curve. The model is said to have better performance if the area under the curve (AUC) is bigger (approaches 1), which your curve is showing.
